# Insider Build: Transfer to a Separate Build of Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, windows-insider, windows-11-v22h2

My current Win 11 installation says it will expire in 10 days; can I upgrade to a different build of Win 11, there are no updates presented at the moment?

- Can I upgrade to a separate build; if so how?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "Can I upgrade to a different build of windows 11." - Only if the build is higher than your current build unless you are willing to perform a clean install of a previous build. Since your system is in the Developer channel, you will find it difficult, to stop receiving Insider Preview builds as builds in that channel are right on the edge of Microsoft's development pipeline. Just so you are tracking `25300.1000` is more than 9 months old.

Comment: You will need [UUPDUMP](https://uupdump.net/) to find an appropriate build that is greater than your current build but also one that is lower than the build that will become 23H2.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the "expire in 10 days" message ? Have you upgraded from Windows 10 and when was it?

Comment: @harrymc - If it's anything like the previous Insider Preview builds, it's is a full screen message, that is displayed when the system boots.  Insider Preview builds are only good for 90-120 days, since newer builds, are almost always released within the timeframe.

Comment: @Ramhound: Right, I didn't notice that build 25300.1000 is Insider. I wonder what a non-developer has to do with such a build.

Comment: @harrymc - It was simply one of many builds in that particular channel. I also suspect the screenshot is what author switched to and wasn't necessarily always configured to as I cannot find that build in any channel.  Which suggests the build was before the channel name changes that happened earlier this year.

Comment: Going back to the stable channel will solve the problem for the poster.

Comment: @harrymc - I can tell that their build makes that impossible given they are already queued to leave the Insider Preview Program per their screenshot. Their build if I am not mistaken is higher than 22H2 and actually a candidate for 24H2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current win 11 installation says that it will expire in 10 days. Can I upgrade to a different build of windows 11.

Your Windows Insider Preview build is from February 15th 2023.  It’s erroneously indicating there are no available updates.

So the only way forward, without performing a clean install, is to upgrade to the current Canary build 25941.1000.  Once you upgrade to the current build, you can opt out of the Windows Insider Preview program, and eventually once Windows 11 22H4 is released you will migrated to the appropriate release channel.  You will want to prevent any upgrade other than 24H2 builds, which will be difficult, since the Canary channel contains builds for multiple future releases of Windows.

It’s impossible to migrate to Windows 11 22H2 without performing a clean install since the build is lower than what you have installed. As you are currently in the Canary channel, or did have that channel selected at one point, that’s likely the reason your not being offered updates properly to a new build through Windows Update.

You can also download the current Canary build from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso?wa=wsignin1.0&lc=1033)

[Windows 11 Insider Preview 25941.1000 (rs_prerelease) amd64](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=7a86b0e9-016d-489c-91a1-46719b3607d1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you prescribed and stopped getting that error message, but to do that I had to switch to the canary channel instead of the dev channel. Let's see how things go. I would really love to avoid doing a reinstall from scratch because I have a lot of configuration set up like back-up tasks and scripts along with a dual boot with fedora and also configured my grub accordingly, so trying my level best not to loose all of that.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - You were not actually on the Developer channel, even though it was selected, since the build was from the Canary channel.

Comment: I changed to the anary channel to access this build

Answer (score 1):

All your problems are because you're using an Insider release which is
not intended to be used for a long period. It's more intended for
developers to test in advance whether their products will still work
when this Windows version will be released on the stable channel.

An Insider release contains unverified and experimental features.
When using it, one should be prepared for malfunctioning features.
It's not a suitable long-term working environment.
Any update you find will be to an even more experimental version
that is even less stable.

I would really then counsel reverting to the stable release version,
which would require a clean install of Windows.
The stability you will gain is worth the trouble.